# Delete Parent of Forked Repository - GitLab

Tags: gitlab

Seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an answer: What happens to a fork of a private repository on GitLab when the parent is deleted?  I found an article stating that deleting the parent repo of a fork in GitHub deletes the forks as well, so I'd like to know if GitLab exhibits the same behavior.